# why ethereum.utils.privtoaddr(priv) generates an address

Tags: python, linux, ethereum, ether

so i was looking at this script
[ethercheck](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asimd/ethercheck/master/eth.py)

and i gave it a private key...some crap i came out with

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364144
```

and to my surprize it came out with and address

```
0x6813eb9362372eef6200f3b1dbc3f819671cba69
```

everything else  seems to work fine. any ideea on why it works with this?

no address at all, an error

LE: so my question is why does it generate and actual address if the private key is invalid?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have a function which you call with a number and get a different number as output. What is "working" or what should not be working?

Comment: Can you edit the question and try to describe your problem better. Now it is unclear what you are asking. Also do not include links - especially non-working links - in your question.

Comment: yeah, the private address is total bogus but it generates an actual valid address. A actual private key will work fine but this bogus one?It's a github script and i droped a "/" at the end by mistake, sorry

Comment: @Testdev01 a private key is basically a very large number, nothing more. Why should the result be different if you choose a different number?